# undefined method `stripe_card_token' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, payment-gateway, erb, stripe-payments

I am trying to integrate stripe to receive payments/donation in my rails4 app. I am getting `undefined method "stripe_card_token" for nil:NilClass` I am not understanding why this is happening.

At first I thought it was a problem with string parameters but it still won't work, not sure why. Did I do a typo that I can't spot? Any guidance appreciated.

charges controller

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @charge = Charge.new
    end

    def create
      @charge = Charge.new(charges_params)
      if @charge.save_with_payment
        redirect_to @charge, :notice => "Thank you for subscribing!"
      else
        render :new
      end
    end

    def charges_params
        params.require(:charge).permit(:stripe_card_token)
    end

end
```

Charges Model:

```
class Charge < ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_accessor :stripe_card_token

    def save_with_payment
      if valid?
        customer = Stripe::Customer.create(card: stripe_card_token)
        self.stripe_customer_token = customer.id
        save!
      end
    rescue Stripe::InvalidRequestError => e
      logger.error "Stripe error while creating customer: #{e.message}"
      errors.add :base, "There was a problem with your credit card."
      false
    end

end
```

My contest#show view:

```
<%= form_for @charge do |f| %>
          <% if @charge.errors.any? %>
            <div class="error_messages">
                <h2><%= pluralize(@charge.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this               charge from being saved: </h2>
                <ul>
                <% @charge.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                    <li><%= msg %></li>
                <% end %>
                </ul>
            </div>
          <% end %>

            <%= f.hidden_field :stripe_card_token %>
            <%= f.hidden_field :contest_id %>
            <%= f.hidden_field :user_id %>

            <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :amount %>
                <%= f.text_field :amount %>
            </div>

            <% if @charges.stripe_card_token.present? %>
              Credit card has been provided.
            <% else %>
              <div class="field">
                <%= label_tag :card_number, "Credit Card Number" %>
                <%= text_field_tag :card_number, nil, name: nil %>
              </div>
              <div class="field">
                <%= label_tag :card_code, "Security Code on Card (CVV)" %>
                <%= text_field_tag :card_code, nil, name: nil %>
              </div>
              <div class="field">
                <%= label_tag :card_month, "Card Expiration" %>
                <%= select_month nil, {add_month_numbers: true}, {name: nil, id: "card_month"} %>
                <%= select_year nil, {start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year+15}, {name: nil, id: "card_year"} %>
              </div>
            <% end %>
            <div id="stripe_error">
              <noscript>JavaScript is not enabled and is required for this form. First enable it in your web browser settings.</noscript>
            </div>

        <% end %>
```

My charges schema table:

```
  create_table "charges", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "stripe_customer_token"
    t.integer  "contest_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.decimal  "amount"
  end
```

My contest controller show action:

```
  def show
    @contest = Contest.find(params[:id])
    @charge = Charge.new
  end
```

Comment: change `@charges` to `@charge` and try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% if @charges.stripe_card_token.present? %>
```

You called it `@charge` in your controller, you've not defined `@charges`

Comment: Such a newb mistake! Damn!!!! THank you so much cant believe I didnt notice that...